# `parskip` removes spacing before `amsthm` theorem environments?

Tags: spacing, theorems, amsthm

I have a spacing problem. Whenever I include a theorem environment, `\begin{theorem}\end{theorem}`, the theorem appears very close to the previous line. The spacing is much less than the normal spacing between lines. Do any one have any idea to change this? I don't just ad hoc add `\vskip` at each theorem environment.

Minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath} % AMS mathmode stuff
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{parskip} % remove auto-indentation of paragraphs with \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{\begin{thm}[#1]\upshape}{\end{thm}}

\begin{document}

 \section{Test}

 Let there be nice spacing.

 \begin{theorem}
  No space for you!
 \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following as output:

[image]

Commenting out `\usepackage{parskip}` causes the following output to be produced:

[image]

Comment: Since this doesn't happen with the standard classes and settings, you should show a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks egreg. I have a quite complicated setting. I include many style files. Please see what I add above

Comment: @Anand: please use backticks to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) for more readabity, I just did that for you. Btw. greeting is not necessary, and the name is already right below the question. Omitting it helps to concentrate on the problem. ;-)

Comment: @Anand: another tip following your edit: if you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Seamus has been so kind to do that.

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz, thank you very much for these comments and your editing of my questions. :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put the following code in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=\parskip \thm@postskip=0pt
}
\makeatother
```

The problem is that **amsthm** sets `\thm@preskip` to `\topsep`, which is zeroed by **parskip**.

Comment: Dear egreg, how to space before definitions? What you proposed works well with theorem but it seems not working for definitions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Anand Sorry, but you should provide a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks egreg for your prompt answer. I have fixed the problem. I changed the theoremstyle and fixed the problem. :-)