# How can I change the spacing around definitions with amsthm?

Tags: spacing, theorems

I am wondering how I may change spacing around definition environments.

I have seen the answer posted for [the same question about theorems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22130/1860),

```
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=\parskip \thm@postskip=0pt
}
\makeatother
```

but am not sure how to edit this to work for definition environment.

Comment: what precisely do you want to do -- make the space larger, or remove it?  there is a style `\newtheoremstyle{remark}` that differs from the `definition` style only by having no additional space above or below.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I would like to have the option of specifying how much space is before the environment, and how much after the environment, similar to the code shown above. However that code only affects theorems, and not definitions. I am wondering how to edit that code so that it does work for definition environments.

Answer (score 2):

this answer presupposes that you are using the `amsthm` package, and not one of the ams document classes, which incorporate the `amsthm` facilities, but sometimes with slightly different assumptions.

you can adapt the spacing around the `definition` environment using this redefinition.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\th@definition}{%
  \normalfont
  \thm@preskip <dimen> \relax
  \thm@postskip <dimen> \relax
}
\makeatother
```

(it isn't necessary to redefine the end of the environment; it's set up this way since often the pre- and post-skips are equated by the statement `\thm@postskip\thm@preskip`, and that is most often done at the same time the preskip is set so that the relation between the settings is more easily recognized.