# Why does amsthm break down in my document?

Tags: spacing

I've written an unfinished document and was advised to use the amsthm package for proofs etc, however when using it, it removed all the spacing between definitions and theorems, why is this the case?

If you need an example, I can happily provide.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\normalfont\bfseries\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item\relax
        {\itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}}\hspace\labelsep\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}  

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
%\bigskip
%\smallskip
\section{Definitions and prerequisites}
Let us recall some basic knowledge, we begin by giving some definitions. 
%\medskip
\begin{definition} 
A group is a set $G$ together with a binary operation $*$ on $G$ satisfying
the following properties:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(G\arabic*),series=group]
\item Closure: $\forall x,y \in G, x * y \in G$.
\item Associativity: $\forall x,y, z \in G, (x * y) * z = x * (y * z)$.
\item Identity: There is an element $e \in G$ such that $e * x = x * e = x$ for all $x \in G$.
\item Inverses: For any $x \in G$ there is an element $y \in G$ such that $x * y = y * x = e$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be the kernel and image of $f$. Note that the kernel and image of $f$ are both invariant subspaces. For the kernel with $x \in W_1$, if $f(x)=0$, then $f\rho_s^1(x) = \rho_s^2f(x)=0$ so $\rho_s^1(x) \in W_1$. By irreducibility, $W_1$ is trivial or the whole space. We neglect the first case as it implies $f=0$ which is trivial. By virtue of the same argument presented above we can conclude the image $W_2$ is equal to $V_2$. Since by assumption $f \neq 0$ we have $W_1 = 0$ and $W_2 = V_2$ which shows $f$ is an isomorphism.
\item $f$ has a non-zero eigenvalue(there exits at least one, since the field of scalars is the field of complex numbers). The map $\hat{f} = f - \lambda I$ satisfies $\rho_s^2 \circ \hat{f} = \hat{f} \circ \rho_s^1$ and has a non-trivial kernel so $\hat{f} = 0$.\qedhere
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parskip` and `amsthm` packages interact badly with each other, you can fix this with the trick from @egregs great answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22130/36296

Alternatively you could leave out the `parskip` package if you don't need it.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\normalfont\bfseries\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item\relax
        {\itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}}\hspace\labelsep\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}

\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=2\parskip \thm@postskip=0pt
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
%\bigskip
%\smallskip
\section{Definitions and prerequisites}
Let us recall some basic knowledge, we begin by giving some definitions. 
%\medskip
\begin{definition} 
A group is a set $G$ together with a binary operation $*$ on $G$ satisfying
the following properties:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(G\arabic*),series=group]
\item Closure: $\forall x,y \in G, x * y \in G$.
\item Associativity: $\forall x,y, z \in G, (x * y) * z = x * (y * z)$.
\item Identity: There is an element $e \in G$ such that $e * x = x * e = x$ for all $x \in G$.
\item Inverses: For any $x \in G$ there is an element $y \in G$ such that $x * y = y * x = e$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be the kernel and image of $f$. Note that the kernel and image of $f$ are both invariant subspaces. For the kernel with $x \in W_1$, if $f(x)=0$, then $f\rho_s^1(x) = \rho_s^2f(x)=0$ so $\rho_s^1(x) \in W_1$. By irreducibility, $W_1$ is trivial or the whole space. We neglect the first case as it implies $f=0$ which is trivial. By virtue of the same argument presented above we can conclude the image $W_2$ is equal to $V_2$. Since by assumption $f \neq 0$ we have $W_1 = 0$ and $W_2 = V_2$ which shows $f$ is an isomorphism.
\item $f$ has a non-zero eigenvalue(there exits at least one, since the field of scalars is the field of complex numbers). The map $\hat{f} = f - \lambda I$ satisfies $\rho_s^2 \circ \hat{f} = \hat{f} \circ \rho_s^1$ and has a non-trivial kernel so $\hat{f} = 0$.\qedhere
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you mention `parskip`? Did I miss a request?

Comment: @Blincer Insider information: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468392/36296 :) I was just writing a comment to the other question when this new question popped up

Comment: @samcarter can I have the empty box at the end of the proof? it looks neater

Comment: @samcarter and can I increase the spacing a tad more between the definitions and theorems?

Comment: @A.E Sure, remove the line `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}  `. Your document explicitly changed this symbol, so I thought this would be what you want.

Comment: @A.E You can change the spacing before the definition for example by using `\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=1.5\parskip \thm@postskip=0pt
}` (replace the 1.5 with whatever value you want)

Comment: @samcarter cheers, much appreciated.

Comment: @A.E You're welcome!

Comment: @samcarter I tried using the above line, but when I implement it, nothing changes, well at least from what I can see

Comment: @A.E 1.5 changes not much. If you want a larger change, replace it with a larger number. In my last edit, I used 2

Comment: @samcarter I tried with 50 and nothing happened!

Comment: @A.E It works fine in my example. Can you make a MWE of the code where it is not working?

Comment: @samcarter ok fixed, so this will add a certain amount of space between theorems and definitions? what if also want to keep the same spacing for propositions, corollaries and lemmas?

Comment: @A.E It won't add space between, but on top of theorems. Works just the same width lemmas etc.

Comment: @samcarter and also looking over the proofs from 2.1.4 onwards, the qed symbol is 1/2 lines after the end of the proof, how can I fix this?

Comment: @A.E Maybe this would be best asked as a new question, including a **Minimal** working example. I have no idea what your proof 2.1.4 might be or how you placed the qed symbol

Comment: @samcarter sure

Answer (score 1):

`amsthm` overrides the default styles for theorems.

You can however customize them with the following syntax

```
\newtheoremstyle{note}% style name 
{2ex}% above space 
{2ex}% below space 
{}% body font 
{}% indent amount 
{\scshape}% head font 
{.}% post head punctuation 
{\newline}% post head punctuation 
{}% head spec 

\theoremstyle{note} 
\newtheorem{scnote}{Note}
```

And later use in your document:

```
\begin{scnote} 
This is an example of a theorem-like environment. 
\end{scnote}
```

Of course you can replace `scnote` by whatever you want.

---

The example is from https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/amsthm.html.